# Why is $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{k(k-1)z^{k-2}} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-2}{(k+1)(k+2)z^k}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

My textbook presents the following as obvious,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{k(k-1)z^{k-2}} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-2}{(k+1)(k+2)z^k}.$$

But I'm not seing how this is the case.

I can see that it is reasonable by computing the first numbers, i.e
${0,0,2,6z,2,6z}$ since $0,0$ wont affect the sum. But how can I prove it?

Comment: The first and second terms in LHS are zero and hence it starts from $k=2$.  Now put $k-2=j$ and replace $j$ by $k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens here is that we note that the first two terms of the summation are indeed 0, so we can rewrite as:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n k(k-1)z^{k-2} = \sum_{k=2}^n k(k-1)z^{k-2}$$
Then we can shift the index of summation down by 2 to get:
$$\sum_{k=2}^n k(k-1)z^{k-2} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-2} (k+2)(k+1)z^{k}$$

Answer (score 0):

You are simply shifting indices. Let's say $a,b,n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $c$ is a function of $k$. Then
$$
\sum_{k=a}^{b}c(k)=c(a)+c(a+1)+\dots+c(b-1)+c(b).
$$
Now shift the summation boundaries by $-n$ and the argument of the function $c$ by $n$. Let's see if the sum is the same. So be more efficient with brackets I assume $+$ is associative. $$
\sum_{k=a-n}^{b-n} c(k+n)=c(a-n+n)+c(a-n+1+n)+\dots+c(b-n-1+n)+c(b-n+n)
$$
$$
=c(a)+c(a+1)+\dots+c(b-1)+c(b)=\sum_{k=a}^{b}c(k).
$$